# How to check if a user has provided an argument discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have just started trying to learn how to code in discord.py. However, I'm not sure how to check if a user has provided an arguement after the command. 
For example, if the user types **!kick**, wihout tagging a user after it, it should give them an error message saying something like **"Please tag a user"**.

So my question is, **How do I check if the user has tagged another user when using a command, and if not, give them an error message**.

Here is my code:

```python
#PyBot by RYAN#2302

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import chalk

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Ready when you are xd")
    print ("I am running on " + bot.user.name)
    print ("With the ID: " + bot.user.id)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await bot.say(":ping_pong: Ping! :ping_pong:")
    print ("!ping")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await bot.say("The users name is: {}".format(user.name))
    await bot.say("The users ID is: {}".format(user.id))
    await bot.say("The users status is: {}".format(user.status))
    await bot.say("The users highest role is: {}".format(user.top_role))
    await bot.say("The user joined at: {}".format(user.joined_at))
    print ("!info")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await bot.say(":boot: Cya, {}. Ya loser!".format(user.name))
    await bot.kick(user)
    print ("!kick on {}".format(user.name))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `user` argument a default value of `None`, and then check to see if a submitted value is used instead

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
if user:    
    await bot.say(":boot: Cya, {}. Ya loser!".format(user.name))
    await bot.kick(user)
    print ("!kick on {}".format(user.name))
else:
    await bot.say("Please tag a user to kick")
```

All `Member` objects will be truthy, so the only time `if user:` will fail is if no user was supplied.  If the input cannot be matched to a user, the command will do nothing, failing silently unless we also specify a error listener

```
@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.BadArgument):
        await bot.say('Could not recognize user')
```